# jQuery Load Page , ASP.NET Error (The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted. )

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I am trying to load a page in a div With jQuery :

> ```
> $(document).ready(function () {
>         $("#Add").click(function (e) {
>             e.preventDefault();
>             $("#test").load("a.aspx");
>         });
>     });
> ```

---

i have a server side ASP.NET button in my current Web Form.
after i loading that page in DIV i received this error  :

> The state information is invalid for
>   this page and might be corrupted.

what is the problem?

Comment: I don't know that much ASP.NET, but I'm guessing that the error occurs because you're trying to load a page with your own JavaScript rather than writing it the ASP.NET way, using an [`UpdatePanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454.aspx) or some such thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you can't do that because of the view state on aspx pages.  if you make your a.aspx page into an html page it should work.  if you are trying to use it like this you might want to consider using a master page or a user control to get the server side aspect of this.

Comment: We used ASP.NET pages fine with no master page, ScriptManager.  Control postbacks can't happen as it won't work right, but we can display popup information in an ASP.NET page with JQuery load.  Sometimes we did get viewstate errors...

Answer (score 1):

You may try to remove the `runat="server"` attribute in your `a.aspx`.

Answer (score 0):

At your a.aspx, you must have < form id="form1" runat="server">, try to remove:
runat="server"